# Proof of $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$ implies $|\lambda|\leq ||T||_{B(X)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, solution-verification, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

I want to show that $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$ implies $|\lambda|\leq ||T||_{B(X)}$ where $\sigma (T)$ is the spectrum of $T$ and $T\in B(X)$. I would like to check my proof here as it is different and possibly simpler than the one in my notes.

Proof:
Let $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$. This implies that $\ker(\lambda I-T)\neq 0$, so $\exists\ u \in \ker(\lambda I -T)$ where $u\neq 0$. Considering this $u$ we have $\lambda I(u) - T(u)=0 \implies \lambda u=T(u)$.Then, taking the norm of both sides, $||\lambda u||=||T(u)|| \implies |\lambda|||u||=||T(u)|| \implies |\lambda|=\frac {||T(u)||} {||u||}=||T(\frac{u}{||u||})||\leq||T||_{B(X)}$

Does this work?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is finite-dimensional? Otherwise being in the spectrum does not imply being an eigenvalue.

Comment: I'm assuming X is a Hilbert space which I forgot to mention, but I think what you suggested may be the issue.

Comment: Indeed, the Hilbert space assumption does not save you from what I wrote :)

Comment: You can consider the following shift operator $$ A: \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N}), \ (x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots) \mapsto (0, x_0, x_1, \dots)$$ then $0\in \sigma(A)$ (as $A$ is not surjective), but it is not an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

You know from the comments that there was an error in your attempt, namely, that $\lambda$ need not be an eigenvalue. This need not even be true if $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space.

The fact that the spectral radius is bounded by $\|T\|$ follows from the Neumann series representation of the resolvent and it is true on general Banach spaces.

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda|>\|T\|.$ Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}T^n$$ converges uniformly and absolutely and $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. In fact we have $$R(\lambda,T)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}T^n.$$
This implies $$\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:|\lambda|> \|T\|\}\subseteq \rho(T).$$ In other words $$\sigma(T)\subseteq\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:|\lambda|\leq \|T\|\}.$$